# How to pass struct argument in brownie-eth?

Tags: solidity, brownie

I tried to pass list of dicts to an argument like this.

```
mycontract.myfunction([{"token1": "...", "token2": "..."}], {"from": account}])
```

it don't work.

this is the struct and function in my solidity contract i tried to pass argument, as an example.

```
struct tokens{ 
    address token1, 
    address token2 
    }

function myfunction(tokens memory params) {
    ...
    }
```

What should i pass as argument for brownie to understand struct form.

Comment: There's a similar question here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/86868/web3-py-transact-call-with-struct-parameter.

Comment: I tried but the interpreter says, expected list or tuples, got bytes.